# How can i call a http POST endpoint with request body using Alamofire Framework

Tags: swift, http-post, alamofire

I am developing an iOS APP and i am new to iOS Development.
To handle http request and responses i opted for Alamofire Framework.

Now i have to make a http post request with body. 
Let me describe a bit more:

My API looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/block/arena/v1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response blockArena (@RequestBody(required = true)  testRequest request) 
    {
        Response response = arenaBlockServiceImpl.block(request);
        return respose;
    }

Class testRequest {
    List<Object> ObjectList1;
    List<Object> ObjectList2;
    private int ObjectList1Count = 0;
    private int ObjectList2Count = 0;

    // and its getters and setters
}
```

=========

Now how can i call my API in iOS swift code (or with Alamofire)? Any possible way to do this is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have Used swiftyJson and its good for handling API's

Answer (score 0):

Build your headers:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
           ]
```

Build your parameters as a [String: Any] dictionary:

```
let parameters: [String, Any] = [
            "name": name as String,
            "id": id as Int,
           ]
```

then build your url:

```
let yourAPI = ""http://yourEndPoint"
let yourEndPoint = "\(yourAPI)//block/arena/v1"
```

and finally make the Alamofire call:

```
Alamofire.request(yourEndPoint, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseData { response in
// process response with codable, or SwiftyJson pod
}
```

with Alamofire you can can also do resposceJSON instead of responseData. I use data because I process the responses with swiftyJson and found that responseData works well

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. But my use case needs to send complex object without doing any additional conversion.